# Extracting Latitude/Longitude from polygon vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, latitude-longitude, vertices

Created a global map by adding the OpenStreetMap and WorldMap layers in QGIS. Drew polygons over that, creating what I believe is a polygon layer.

I've also created a layer of the Nodes/Vertices of the Polygon by clicking `Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Vertices` (see photo).

Would like to extract the latitude and longitude of these polygon points (CSV, GeoJSON, or somehow connect to MSQLServer eventually).

I've tried adding calculated fields to the Attribute Tables of the Vertices layer following but am new to GIS and have been unsuccessful.

[image: Example of the Polygons I'm trying to get the latitude/longitude of]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open your attribute table of the layer you want to add this information to and its field calculator. Create a new field with data type double/real and give it a length and precision of your choice. Name it x/lng and y/lat and insert the expression

```
x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

for longitude and

```
y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

for latitude.

This expression will work with every source crs, so you do not need to care about that. In case your layers crs already is EPSG:4326, it would be enough to just enter the expression `$x` or `$y`.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to directly add the latitude and longitude of the vertices in the polygon layer itself ? I have a polyline and want to the do the same. I want the lat lon of the head and the tail node of each line in the polyline layer.

Comment: With a precision of 8, shouldn't the length be 11? The tooltip for Output field length says "Total length of the field (including the number of digits after the decimal place for decimal fields). For example, 123.45 requires a decimal field length of 5".

Comment: @mrXsquared I want to do the same but I would like to get only one coordinate for my polygon with a format that looks like something similar to 54° 5' 0.0096'' N and 12° 6' 31.7196'' E. Do you know how to do?

Answer (score 10):

If you need latitude and longitude as csv you may simply right click your vertices layer and choose **Export > Save Features as...**:

[image]

Then in the dialogue chose **Comma Separated Value [CSV]** in the combo box on top:

[image]

Chose a file name and if applies various restrictions for the output (attributes to export, extent,...). Scroll down and under **Layer Options** select the output format for your coordinates (here I chose 'AS_XY'). *Note the tooltip!*

[image]

The result will be something like (opened in Notepad++):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another approach utilizes the QGIS's native geoalgorithms.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'test'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Use the ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices)

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Add X/Y fields to layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-x-y-fields-to-layer). On this stage set up the Coordinate System appropriately

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** (Optional) Do whatever you want :)
e.g. export the result of the *Step 2* as a CSV file via `RMC > Export > Save Feature As...`

Comment: I like especially step 3 .... :-))))